# BAT script error

Tags: batch-file

I have a script where i try to open a file:

```
IF NOT "%1"=="" goto :skipOpenResult
CALL:ECHORED "Open result file? Y[yes] or N[exit]"
choice /c yn /n
if %errorlevel%==1 
(   
    if exist %resultFile% 
    (
        start %resultFile%
    ) 
    else 
    (
        CALL:ECHORED "File not found: %resultFile%"
    )
)
:skipOpenResult
```

Which means: if i pass a parameter from command line - skip asking for file opening, otherwise ask and open or not.
I am getting "The syntax of the command is incorrect." and i can't figure out why.
Do you hany any solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Check out your [`if` syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) and the locations of the parentheses. Of course `%resultFile%` must not be empty, and consider to put `""` around it...

Comment: All built-in Windows console commands have a help file.  You can read the help file for any of these commands by typing a forward slash and question mark after the command name.  So if you open up a cmd prompt you can type: `if /?`. You will clearly see the syntax for using parentheses.

Comment: Wow... thanks guys! Problem solved. I would never think to that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, *excluding the pointless coloring of text*:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~1"=="" GOTO skipOpenResult
CHOICE /N /M "Open result file? Y[yes] or N[exit]"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 EXIT /B
IF EXIST "%resultFile%" (
    START "" "%resultFile%"
) ELSE ECHO "File not found: %resultFile%"

:skipOpenResult
```